# javascript variables

Tags: javascript

I need to access javascript variable:

`var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {    
  geocoder.geocode({    
    latLng: pos    
  }, function(responses) {  
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {  
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);  
    } else {  
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');  
    }  
  });  
}  

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {  
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;  
}  

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {  
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [  
    latLng.lat(),  
    latLng.lng()  
  ].join(', ');  
}  

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {  
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;  
} 



function initialize() {  

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'london'}, function(results, status) {
   rr = results[0].geometry.location;
});

 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(rr);  

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {  
    zoom: 8,  
    center: latLng,  
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });  

  // Update current position info.  
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);  
  geocodePosition(latLng);  

  // Add dragging event listeners.  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {  
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');  
  });  

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {  
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');    
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());  
  });  

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {  
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');  
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());  
  });  


// Onload handler to fire off the app.  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This is whole script I need to get near address first so pass somehow address to convert to ltlng

Comment: @user438755 - Please indent each line of your code 4 spaces, or it is not formatted as code.

Comment: @Peter - So what I write all day long, using 2 spaces, is not formatted as code?

Comment: @Jakob [Nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/64504#64504). ----- but it looks like you often [do use 4 spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467820/xy-z5-how-are-parts-of-this-expression-called/3467922#3467922).

Comment: @Peter - Haha, touché! (but more for going through the trouble of finding an example rather than the actual spacing-fail, since I just copied that statement from the grammar) :D

Answer (score 4):

You have to access it or pass it somewhere in the callback, like this:

```
var rr;      
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'london'}, function(results, status) {
  rr = results[0].geometry.location;
  alert(rr);    
});
```

Or pass it to another function to do additional work with the data:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'london'}, function(results, status) {
  anotherFunction(results[0].geometry.location);
});
```

That anonymous function is the callback for the `geocode()` function, meaning it runs *later*, so `rr` is getting set *after* your `alert()` currently.

Comment: so when passed to anotoher function how can I retrieve variable inside first function?

Comment: @user438755 - In the second example above, you would have another function, `function anotherFunction(loc) { alert(loc); }` for example, you can do whatever you want with that parameter, since that function will be called with it...when the server response comes back and the data is ready.

Comment: but i need to access this variable in function where geocoder.geocode is just outside: var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(rr);

Comment: You have to understand that these functions run asynchronously, so you have to code to handle that; no other option.

Comment: @user438755 - The data simply isn't available, it's an asynchronous operation, you need to run the rest of your code *when the data is available*, and that means from the callback.

Comment: I've edited the post with whole script the idea is i need to pass address first for starting position and than adjust

Comment: @user438755 - you'd simply call any update code inside you callback function, that includes the map updates, etc...I don't see you using a callback in the map at all though.

Comment: yes i've added this inside initialize function [edited again] to get first coordinates from address so later can adjust it. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: @user438755 - You need to put all of that code in your callback, or at least trigger it from there, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mPmAn/

Comment: also tried to write it as cookie but don't work either cookie reading is ok however doesn't work   var rr = readCookie('jeaddress').substr(1,22).toString();  
alert(rr);

Answer (score 0):

The call is asynchronous meaning that the `geocoder.geocode` will return immediately and only inside the anonymous callback function you are able to access it.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'london'}, function(results, status) {
   alert(results[0].geometry.location);
});
```

Comment: but I need to get result outside how to do it?

Comment: You might need many things, the question here is that you cannot have them until they are available, which in your case is the anonymous callback function. So if you want to use AJAX you will have to adapt the way you think and structure your application in an event-oriented manner.